# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: member is not defined discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Im using discord.js for bot making, and i keep getting this error when im trying to make a music bot?? I dont know how to define member. it also wont even join the channel or obviously play music, the only thing that works is the function that tells theres a link needed for the bot to continue

```
let args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");

switch (args[0]) {
    case 'play':

    function play(connection, message){
        var server = severs[message.guild.id];

        server.dispatcher = connection.playStream(ytdl(server.queue[0], {filter: "audio"}));

        server.queue.shift();

        server.dispatcher.on("end", function(){
            if(server.queue[0]){
                play(connection, message);
            }
            else {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        });
    }


    if(!args[1]){
        message.channel.send("Link needed!");
        return;
    }

    if(!message.member.voiceChannel){
        message.channel.send("You must be in a channel!");
        return;
    }
    if(!servers[message.guild.id]) servers[message.guild.id] = {
        queue: []
    };

    var server = servers[message.guild.id];

    server.queue.push(args[1]);

    var server = servers[message.guild.id];

    server.queue.push(args[1]);

    if(!message.guild.voiceConnection) member.voiceChannel.join().then(function(connection){
        play(connection, message);
    });
      break;
     case "skip" :
        var server = servers[message.guild.id];
        if (server.dispatcher) server.dispatcher.end();
        break;

        case "stop":
            var server = server[message.guild.id];

            if(message.guild.voiceConnection) message.guild.voiceConnection.disconnect();

        break;



}
```

Answer (score 1):

Where did the error occur? But based on:

```
if(!message.member.voiceChannel){
    message.channel.send("You must be in a channel!");
    return;
}
```

Did you mean

`message.member.voiceChannel.join().then(`

instead of

`member.voiceChannel.join().then(`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about much on scripting or discord.js, but
you could use `connection.play()` instead of `connection.playStream()`